# How to find the location of automatic S3 backups generated by Amazon RDS?

Tags: mysql, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, database-backups, amazon-rds

I've read that Amazon RDS automatically backs up your database to S3. I'm wondering how can I actually see these backups and their contents?

The reasons I want to see them are:

1. I'm paranoid, am new to the service and haven't experienced a failure to know that the backup process will actually work.
2. I've read that the backups don't work if some of your tables are MyISAM. That is, I need to have all my tables be InnoDB and not a mix of the two for the s3 backups to be generated.

Does anyone have more information on this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, you can't access the S3 bucket RDS uses. If you'd like to confirm that the backups work, you can restore to a point in time via the RDS console. This creates a new RDS instance that uses the backup for that point in time.

Comment: -@ceejayoz, thanks for the tips, I'll test this out, can you confirm or deny this bit about all tables needing to be innoDB in order for the backups to actually work?

Comment: The docs say: "Amazon RDS automated backups and DB Snapshots are currently supported for only the InnoDB storage engine. Use of these features with other MySQL storage engines, including MyISAM, may lead to unreliable behavior while restoring from backups. Specifically, since storage engines like MyISAM do not support reliable crash recovery, your tables can be corrupted in the event of a crash. For this reason, we encourage you to use the InnoDB storage engine." http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.BackingUpUpAndRestoringAmazonRDSInstances.html